# dot graph graphviz - Produce graph for nearest x branches from selected node

Tags: python-3.x, graphviz, dot, pygraphviz

I am working with huge generated .dot graph file (not generated by me but by an application). Is it possible using graphviz to generate the graph showing only the nearest x branches to a node. This will make the graph more comprehensible instead of an extremely large mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a **GVPR** program named **knbhd** that seems to do what you want.   On my Linux (fedora) system I found it here: **/usr/share/graphviz/gvpr/knbhd**.
It seemed to work with this commandline:

```
 X=5; node="yournodename" 
 gvpr -a $X -a $node -f /usr/share/graphviz/gvpr/knbhd   yourfile.gv
```